# Visual Studio Code, php executablePath no docker

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Estou usando o visual studio code com docker, mas nao consigo fazer o VSC enxergar o executável do php. Se instalo o php na minha máquina ele enxerga normal. Mas via docker, sem sucesso.
Alguem pode ajudar? Grato.

Comment: Olha se um desse links tem a resposta https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13356 e aqui tb https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/533

Comment: Agradeco a ajuda. Porém esses links sao quando o php esta instalado na máquina. Na minha máquina uso o docker que cria um ambiente virtual e entao uso o php. O IntellIJ IDEA consegue "enxergar" o ambiente virtualizado e usa o php de lá. Já o vscode nao consigo fazer essa configuracao. Já perdi quase o dia inteiro.